# Loading screen approach in javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx, loading

My application takes some time to make some computations and I want the user to see a loading bar or a pop-up window telling him that the application is doing computations.

I have seen a few examples but none seems to convince me. Can anyone suggest me which would be the best method to apply here, and if it is possible to offer me a practical example.

I thought of a dialog window to tell the user that the program is making some computations but i really don't think that it's a good ideea. Another solution would have been to implement a progress bar, but i don't know if it's the best solution and the implementation would have been quite hard. I've asked because i wanted to know which would be the best solution from a professional point of view

Comment: Please describe in more detail of your non-convincement. To suggest the best one among them methods, you need also provide those methods to us.

Comment: I thought of a dialog window to tell the user that the program is making some computations but i really don't think that it's a good ideea. Another solution would have been to implement a progress bar, but i don't know if it's the best solution and the implementation would have been quite hard. I've asked because i wanted to know which would be the best solution from a professional point of view

Comment: Please improve your question by editing it, instead of comments.